# Symfony 2.3 assets_version not showing with assetic but showing with assets

Tags: symfony, assetic

I would like to use the parameters assets_version for my css and js files. It works well with them when I use {{ asset(bla/bla/file.css) }} but not when I use Assetic.

In this later case, assets_version just doesn't show.

I made the commande php app/console assetic:dump but it still doesn't show...

If anyone could help me on this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Basically my problem was that I wasn't using the function asset.

I had that:

`{% stylesheets 
    'bundles/webapp/css/funCommon.css'
    'bundles/webapp/css/funMobile.css
    filter='?yui_css'
%}
    <link rel=stylesheet href='{{ asset_url }}'>
{% endstylesheets %}`

Instead of that:

`{% stylesheets    'bundles/webapp/css/funCommon.css'
    'bundles/webapp/css/funMobile.css
    filter='?yui_css'
%}
    <link rel=stylesheet href='{{ asset(asset_url) }}'>
{% endstylesheets %}`